# Windows 7 start menu: restore the search input field

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

The start menu on my Windows 7 Pro does not show the search input field (for, e.g., searching programs). How can I restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable Windows Search, click on **Start** and select **Control Panel**.

[image]

In Control Panel switch to **Large Icons View** and click on **Programs and Features**.

[image]

Next in the left panel click on the **Turn Windows features on or off** hyperlink.

[image]

Scroll down the list and **check** the box next to **Windows Search**.

[image]

Now click **Ok** in the **Windows Features** window.

[image]

Then a restart is required to complete the changes.

[image]

— **Source:** [How-To Geek - How to enable/disable Search in Windows 7?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/)

---

Also, hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then start `gpedit.msc`.

[image]

Under **Computer Configuration** and **User Configuration**, repeat twice:

1. Open **Administrative Templates**, then **All Settings**.
2. Sort by **State**, check for anything enabled/disabled.
3. Sort the **State** again in the **opposite** direction, check again.
4. Do you see anything search related that is configured?